# Implementing the command pattern in a RESTful API

Tags: design-patterns, api, rest, api-design, http

I'm in the process of designing an HTTP API, hopefully making it as RESTful as possible.

There are some actions which functionality spreads over a few resources, and sometime needs to be undone.

I thought to myself, this sounds like a command pattern, but how can I model it into a resource?

I will introduce a new resource named XXAction, like DepositAction, which will be created through something like this

```
POST /card/{card-id}/account/{account-id}/Deposit
AmountToDeposit=100, different parameters...
```

this will actually create a new DepositAction and activate it's Do/Execute method.
In this case, returning a 201 Created HTTP status means the action has been executed successfully.

Later if a client wishes to look at the action details he can

```
GET /action/{action-id}
```

Update/PUT should be blocked I guess, because it is not relevant here.

And in order to Undo the action, I thought of using

```
DELETE /action/{action-id}
```

which will actually call the Undo method of the relevant object, and change it's status.

Let's say I'm happy with only one Do-Undo, I don't need to Redo.

**Is this approach ok?**

**Are there any pitfalls, reasons not to use it?**

**Is this understood from the POV of the clients?**

Comment: Short answer, that's not REST.

Comment: @EvanPlaice care to elaborate on that? that's exactly the question.

Comment: I would have elaborated in an answer but Gary's answer already covers most/all of what I'd add. I say it's not rest because URIs are only supposed to represent resources (ie not actions). Actions are handled through GET/POST/PUT/DELETE/HEAD. Think of REST as an OOP interface. The goal being to make the API fit the general pattern and decouple it from implementation specific details as possible.

Comment: @EvanPlaice Ok I understand, thanks. I think it's confusing here because Deposit could be thought of as a noun and as a verb...

Comment: In this case the URI should represent a transaction where debiting (taking money) and crediting (giving money) are actions done via POST requests. POST is used for both because each time money is moved in either direction it represents a new transaction being created. In your specific case, the transactions are taking place on a cardholder's account so the card's account number is the resource URI.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**You're adding in a layer of abstraction that is confusing**

Your API starts off very clean and simple. A HTTP POST creates a new Deposit resource with the given parameters. Then you go off the rails by introducing the idea of "actions" that are an implementation detail rather than a core part of the API.

As an alternative consider this HTTP conversation...

> POST /card/{card-id}/account/{account-id}/Deposit
>
> AmountToDeposit=100, different parameters...
>
> 201 CREATED
>
> Location=/card/123/account/456/Deposit/789

Now you want to undo this operation (technically this should not be allowed in a balanced accounting system but what the hey):

> DELETE /card/123/account/456/Deposit/789
>
> 204 NO CONTENT

The API consumer knows that they are dealing with a Deposit resource and is able to determine what operations are permitted on it (usually through OPTIONS in HTTP).

Although the implementation of the delete operation is conducted through "actions" today there is no guarantee that when you migrate this system from, say, C# to Haskell and maintain the front end that the secondary concept of an "action" would continue to add value, whereas the primary concept of Deposit certainly does.

**Edit to cover an alternative to DELETE and Deposit**

In order to avoid a delete operation, but still effectively remove the Deposit you should do the following (using a generic Transaction to allow for Deposit and Withdrawal):

> POST /card/{card-id}/account/{account-id}/Transaction
>
> **Amount=-100**, different parameters...
>
> 201 CREATED
>
> Location=/card/123/account/456/Transation/790

A new Transaction resource is created which has exactly the opposite amount (-100). This has the effect of balancing the account back to 0, negating the original Transaction.

You might consider creating a "utility" endpoint like

> POST /card/{card-id}/account/{account-id}/Transaction/789/Undo    <- BAD!

to get the same effect. However, this breaks the semantics of a URI as being an identifier by introducing a verb. You are better off sticking to nouns in identifiers and keeping operations constrained to the HTTP verbs. That way you can easily create a permalink from the identifier and use it for GETs and so on.

Comment: +1 "technically this should not be allowed in a balanced accounting system". Somebody knows how to count beans. That statement is absolutely correct, the way to reverse would be to create another transaction crediting the funds back. General ledger entries should always be considered immutable and permanent once a transaction is completed.

Comment: So, if I change, in my questions, instead of Delete /action/... to Delete /deposit/... is it ok?

Comment: @EvanPlaice Why can't I just undo the action?

Comment: @Mithir I would avoid exposing action at all - it's fine as an implementation approach. Generally, it is useful to treat user interactions with resources as entries in a (non-financial) ledger to allow a view through time of their work.

Comment: @GaryRowe So it's still a resource no? this view of interactions of the user, I can hide the creation but I need to expose retrieving no?

Comment: @GaryRowe Your answer was very informative, but can you please suggest an alternative?

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mithir I was describing the accounting rule. In a standard double-entry bookkeeping system you never remove transactions. History once committed is considered immutable to keep people honest. In your case you could still use a DELETE action but on the back-end (ex general ledger database table) you'd add another transaction representing crediting (ie giving back) the money back to the user. I'm no bean counter (ie accountant) but it's one of the standard practices taught in a "Principles of Accounting I" course.

Comment: (cont) Database logs use transactions in a similar manner. That's why it's possible to replicate and/or rebuild a dataset using only the logs. As long as the transactions are replayed in the chronologically, it should be possible to rebuild the dataset from any point in its history. Removing mutability from the equation ensures consistency.

Comment: @GaryRowe about the edit, what you are describing isn't a deposit, I think names are important here in order to distinguish different actions... Is it the same if I call it something like CancelledDeposit?

Comment: Fair enough just rename it to Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason for REST existence is resilience against network errors. To which end all operations should be **idempotent**.

The basic approach seems reasonable, but the way you describe the `DepositAction` creation does not sound to be idempotent, which should be fixed. By having *client* provide unique ID that will be used to detect duplicate requests. So the creation would change to

```
PUT /card/{card-id}/account/{account-id}/Deposit/{action-id}
AmountToDeposit=100, different parameters...
```

If another PUT to the same URL is made with the same content as previously, the response should still be `201 created` if the content is the same and error if the content is different. This allows the client to simply retransmit the request when it fails, since the client can't tell whether the request or response got lost.

It makes more sense to use PUT, because it just writes the resource and is idempotent, but using POST wouldn't really cause any problem either.

To look at the transaction details the client will `GET` the same URL, i.e.

```
GET /card/{card-id}/account/{account-id}/Deposit/{action-id}
```

and to undo it, it can DELETE it. But if it actually has anything to do with money as the sample suggests, I would suggest PUTting it with added "cancelled" flags instead though for accountability (that there remains trace of created and cancelled transaction).

Now you need to choose a method of creating the unique id. You have several options:

1. Issue client-specific prefix earlier in the exchange that must be included.
2. Add a special POST request to get blank unique ID from the server. This request does not have to be idempotent (and can't, really), because unused IDs don't really cause any trouble.
3. Simply use UUID. Everybody uses them and nobody seems to have any problem with neither the MAC-based ones nor the random ones.

Comment: From What I know, POST is not idempotent.http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)#Affecting_server_state

Comment: @Mithir: POST is not assumed to be idempotent; it still can be. But it's true that since all REST operations are supposed to be idempotent, POST has basically no place in REST.

Comment: I'm confused... content I've read and existing implementation I'm familiar with(ServiceStack, ASP.NET Web API), all suggests that POST has a place in REST.

Comment: @Mithir: Actually POST is used even in one of the suggestions above, for getting fresh ID. But for resilience against errors, most things need to be idempotent and such would not use POST.

Comment: In REST idempotence is assigned to the resource, not the protocol or its response codes. Thus, in REST over HTTP the methods GET, PUT, DELETE, PATCH and so on are considered idempotent although their response codes may vary for subsequent calls. POST is idempotent in the sense that every call creates a new resource. See Fielding's [It is OK to use POST](http://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2009/it-is-okay-to-use-post).

Comment: Operations that are not idempotent are allowed in rest.  That assertion is flat out wrong.

Comment: @GaryRowe ‘POST is idempotent in the sense that every call creates a new resource.’ No, POST does not have to create a new resource; the semantics (intended effect) of this method is resource specific (cf. RFC 7231, [§ 4.3.3](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)). So no, POST is not always idempotent.

Comment: ‘But it's true that since all REST operations are supposed to be idempotent’ Where did you read that in [Fielding’s thesis](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm)?

Comment: @Maggyero Yep, that works for me. Personally, I tend to use POST only on resource creation relying on PUT etc for updates to ensure there's no confusion but it's not strictly necessary.